# How to develop bluemix CAM

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-automation-manager

Is there any github source where IBM Cloud automation manager source code is there? Can I extend CAM's functionalities? Or should I extend terraform's capabilties instead?

Answer (score 0):

IBM Cloud Automation Manager running on ICP platform has the ability to deploy bluemix templates built in.  Use the "IBM Cloud" connection type to build your connection data, and then you can use the already included.

For details on the connection see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2L37_2.1.0.1/cam_creating_ibm_cloud_connection.html

For details on what the IBM Cloud terraform provider can do check it's github here:
https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/terraform-provider-ibm